# Tensorflow Tensor values are not assigned

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor, loss-function

I'm using a custom loss function as below:
`model.compile(loss=custom_loss,...)`

And the custom loss function is defined as:

```
def custom_loss(y_actual,y_pred):
    custom_loss = loss_function(y_actual,y_pred) + penalty * quantizer.model_size()
    return custom_loss
```

where `quantizer` is a object of a class and `model_size()` is a method of this class. In this `model_size()` method, I'm trying to create some tensors variable with some initial value. But it seems like the value is not assigned. I'm printing using `print(tf.constant(1.0, dtype=float))` and `print(tf.Variable(1.0, dtype=float))` to see the tensors and the output is like `Tensor("custom_loss/Const:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)` and `<tf.Variable 'custom_loss/Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32>`. What causes this issue?